# Interpreter typing in C

Tags: c, interpreter, typing

I'm developing an interpreter and I have some questions to it.

I recently saw a small C interpreter that used a very simple struct like the below for all its objects/values in the language:

```
struct Object
{
    ubyte type;
    ubyte value;
};
```

This struct can hold strings, integers, bools and lists (I think) used in the language the interpreter is working with.

- How can you get this Object struct to hold all these types?

Comment: are you sure that value is `ubyte`?

Answer (score 2):

> How can you get this Object struct to hold all these types?

It doesn't hold the value it just holds IDs/references to the values which are stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's done like sbi suggests, so the interpreter's struct would look more like:

```
struct Object
{
    ubyte type;
    void* value;
};
```

The actual value would be allocated somewhere on the heap, and when the object was constructed, the interpreter would note the type in `ubyte type`. Later, functions would note the type using `object.type` and alias the value to that type, or just assume that it was the correct type, like this:

```
useObjectAsString(Object toUse) 
{
    char* data = (char*)toUse.value;
}
```

If you just have a few types you want to implement, you could also try using a [union.](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/unions.html)